# Making a plot with two strings

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make a piece wise plot of `1/(1+25x^2)` cut into ten pieces. I have two strings which are correct, they give me x and `f(x)` values from `-1` to `1`.

```py
n = 10
#generating a x set
mylistx = []

for x in range(0, n):
    u = ((2/(n)) * (x+1))-1
    mylistx.append(str(u))
print (mylistx)

#generating y values
mylisty = []
for x in range(0, n):
    u = ((2/(n)) * (x+1))-1
    p = (1/(1+25*(u**2)))
    mylisty.append(str(p))
print (mylisty)
```

Output strings:

```
['-0.8', '-0.6', '-0.4', '-0.2', '0.0', '0.2', '0.4', '0.6', '0.8', '1.0']
['0.058', '0.1', '0.2', '0.5', '1.0', '0.5', '0.2', '0.1', '0.0588', '0.038464']
```

But when I plot them using the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(mylistx, mylisty, label='(1+25x^2)^-1')
plt.show()
```

It gets real messed up and starts plotting them out of order and everything. Its just two 10 cell long strings. Why is it printing them out of order and only connecting 4 dots?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the values are appended to the lists as strings. They need to be numbers.

Also note that making use of [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/), everything can be written quite concise. [`np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) creates an array with 1000 x-values in the range between -1 and 1. And by the magic of [vectorization](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html), just writing `1 / (1 + 25 * (x ** 2))` creates an array with the function values.

Some code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
plt.plot(x, 1 / (1 + 25 * (x ** 2)), label='$(1+25x^2)^{-1}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily making things complicated. You don't need to convert things to strings. Instead of converting the values to string, just append them as they are in floats using

```
mylistx.append(u)

mylisty.append(p)
```

Still, if you are wondering how you can make your solution work, you can `map` the lists of strings to `float` type and then plot them as

```
plt.plot(list(map(float, mylistx)), list(map(float, mylisty)), '-bo', label='(1+25x^2)^-1')
```

Both the above solutions will generate the following graph:

[image]